# how to convert text to rtf, for sending email?

Tags: .net, smtp

Since I need to send email by code, I'm currently using plan text but since outlook, by default, remove the extra line break it screw up my formatting and I don't want that, I tried to put my text into html but now the email is marked as spam.

My last choice is to move the text into rtf but now my question is.

**What is the easiest way to move text into rtf?**

There is no user interface.

The email doesn't contain complex stuff, only text and some extra line, which is my current issue with plain text and default setting of outlook.

And no, I cannot change the default setting of outlook.

Comment: Unless you can be sure that the recipient also uses Outlook, sending an RTF body is probably a pretty bad idea...  
If your HTML mail is marked as spam there's very probably something else in there that is triggering this.  
My gut-instinct tells me that about 70% of all emails nowadays are HTML (probably even more). It would be pretty bad if all of them were automatically classified as spam...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms and then use the RichTextBox:

```
string text = "your text here";
string rtfText = string.Empty;
using(RichTextBox rtf = new RichTextBox()) {
    rtf.Text = text;
    rtfText = rtf.Rtf;
}
```

Comment: that did the job but I should have looked before if the system.net.mail was actually supporting sending as RTF and it doesn't, it seem you need to play with interop (outlook or word) to do that and that is a big no for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want Outlook to mess with it at all, use MIME type "application/binary".
You won't get to see the code in the preview pane any more -- is that important to you?

Answer (score 0):

Really Nice ur code, for use with VB.net i change some lines:

```
Dim text As String = dr.Item("Descripcion")
Dim rtfText As String = String.Empty
Dim rtf As New RichTextBox
rtf.Text = Text
rtfText = rtf.Rtf
Me.RichTextBox1.Rtf = rtfText
```

I hope this be usefull